# How I can detect facebook comments widget submit?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-widgets

I won't detect submit button event in facebook comment widget.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
I have code:

```
<div data-href="http://${request.getServerName()}:${request.getServerPort().toString()}/n${itemId}"
     class="fb-comments"
     data-width="100%"
     data-numposts="10"
     data-colorscheme="light"
     data-notify="true"
    >
</div>
```

and after I tryed call facebook event but it doesn work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(;
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response);
    });
</script>
```

Whot I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
            console.info("##############");
            console.info(response);
        });

});
```

І resolve my problem.